# How to deal with forum-style questions (i.e. self answers which are edits/updates) at larger scale

Tags: discussion, flags, self-answer

I came across [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/377851/forum-style-questions-multiple-self-answers-from-asker?MaxUserRep=10) which allows to find questions with multiple answers from the OP.

Most of these "answers" are no real answers but should have been an edit to the original question, but those users seemingly did not understand Stack Overflow's Q&A style but treated the answers as posts in a regular forum.

I even found a [very obscure "question"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32754723/insert-validationof) (it does not contain a question but a strange citation of [a book](https://books.google.com/books?id=M-5HBlbJ-OYC&lpg=PA76&ots=g5bfOca8t9&dq=%22This%20political-sociological%20fact%20and%20their%20distinctive%20ethnic%20character%22&hl=en&pg=PA76#v=onepage&q=%22This%20political-sociological%20fact%20and%20their%20distinctive%20ethnic%20character%22&f=false)) and was automatically protected since the OP dumped a lot of code as multiple "answers".

I flagged a few answers out of the SEDE list, but since the query returns over 800 potential forum-style questions, I wonder:

1. How could those misplaced "answers" be removed at large scale (aside from manually flagging)?
2. Is there an automatic system which warns / stops the user when he obviously does not answer his question but just posts updates etc. which should have been an edit to the original question?

Comment: It's weird that the "question" was edited twice after being protected.  No one thought to raise a flag to close/delete the question?

Comment: @ryanyuyu well I flagged it :)

Comment: With 800 results in the query (at least some of which are likely legitimate) and *millions* of questions, I'd say that the existing processes for discouraging non-answers (of which there are quite a lot) are doing a pretty decent job.  If there is a *specific* change that you think SE could make to better discourage people posting non-answers, then by all means, share it.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33180219/how-to-use-addkeylistener-after-removekeylistener) also shows up in the list, but it's not in the category of multiple OP answers. Also, the rep filter is probably excluding some.  If someone did this in '09, and learned the error of their ways, they may have significantly higher rep. Raising the limit to a modest 5k finds [this gem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85/flat-file-databases) from the stone age. (To be continued...)

Comment: (from previous) I modified the query to produce [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/378789/forum-style-questions-multiple-self-answers-from-asker) which grabs the top 1000 sorted by the number of times self-answered and filters the ones older than Jan 1, 2010.

Comment: @Sayse: the number of flags per day is limited AFAIK

Comment: @Thomas yes, they are [How many flags does a user have per day?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149659/how-many-flags-does-a-user-have-per-day); so it's not that easy to remove those answers all at once by manually flagging

Comment: @Sayse the query of course also returns recent non-answers; however one of the reason of this post at meta was to raise awareness of this issue

Comment: @theB since SEDE is [updated only once a week](http://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq) I guess the query might contain some questions for which the non-answers have already been deleted (especially the most recent ones which are still active)

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Hooray for community moderation! The system works.

Comment: Certainly the query may contain things that have been edited/deleted and probably still includes things that shouldn't be included.  (And the counter-example I linked may have a recently deleted answer I can't see.) Still SEDE is a useful tool for finding things even if it is, at worst, a week behind.

Comment: Sorry everyone for the 8000 updates, but, I updated the [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/378789/forum-style-questions-multiple-self-answers-from-asker) to filter out questions that are already closed, and tweaked the sort order so it's sorted by number of self-answers, **then** by date newest->oldest. Which leads to this [I-don't-even-know-what-to-call-it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766857/css-ellipse-clipping-mask-on-bottom-only) with 6 self answers. And whatever [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32207128/how-to-reinitialize-a-neo4j-query) is with 5.

Comment: Wow, 3 code edits on that question all by different users. Not one thinks "this is complete nonsense".

Comment: When answering their own post more than once, does a user got notified with something like _"answers are for **answers**, make sure this isn't just an added note or further detail of your question"_?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan I just checked what happens when you click on "answer" in one of your own questions: You get a popup rather clearly discouraging non-answers: https://i.imgur.com/rxrc1Yd.png ; however I don't know if there are more vigorous notifications once you add more than one self-answer

Comment: @m.s. I didn't know that existed. I wonder about more vigorous responses in particular because I can't imagine there's many *useful* instances where someone has self answered multiple answers.